# How to configure Flutter Flavor for different API links

Tags: flutter, dart, environment, staging

I have 3 different API links for Staging, Development and Production Stages. I tried to configure the files in this way to share links

```
//Types of flavors we have
import 'dart:io';

//Types of flavors
enum Flavor {
  STAGING,
  DEVELOPMENT,
  PRODUCTION,
}

class Config {
  //Floavor is the way to devide application
  //configurations depending on stage we work
  static Flavor? appFlavor;

  // api url for requests depending on the flavor
  // you can use it by typing Config.api_url
  static String get api_url {
    switch (appFlavor) {
      case Flavor.PRODUCTION:
        return 'https://api.Link1';
      case Flavor.DEVELOPMENT:
        return 'https://api.Link2';
      case Flavor.STAGING:
        return 'https://api.Link3';
      default:
        return 'https://api.Link2';
    }
  }

  //getting information about platform
  //you can use it by typing Config.platform
  static String get platform => Platform.isAndroid ? 'ANDROID' : 'IOS';
}
```

Then I initialise the flavor in main.dart in the following way :

```
void main() {
//Initialising the flavor
  Config.appFlavor = Flavor.PRODUCTION;
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    log(details.exceptionAsString(), stackTrace: details.stack);
  };

  runZonedGuarded(
    () => runApp(const IChazy()),
    (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
  );
}
```

But then when I try to pass the data to Chopper package for baseURL it shows me mistake that I should use the const value:

```
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'package:ichazy/config/flavor_config.dart';
//part 'challenges_api_service.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: Config.api_url) //Error Appears here
abstract class ChallengeApiService {}
```

The Error:
**Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression.**

I know that I should use const value in order to cancel this error but in the same time I want to switch flavors and API links. Is there any proper way to somehow manage this two goals, maybe by changing Config class?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to use custom create method in the chopper package

```
@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '/')
abstract class ChallengeApiService extends ChopperService {
  @Get()
  Future<Response> getChallenges(
    @Body() Map<String, dynamic> body,
  );

  static ChallengeApiService create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
        baseUrl: Config.api_url,
        services: [_$ChallengeApiService()],
        converter: JsonConverter());
    return _$ChallengeApiService(client);
  }
}
```